# Picker View and Text Fields numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am working on when a user clicks a text field a picker view is displayed. there are multiple text fields and picker views.
I am able to complete the numberOfRowsInComponent but not the numberOfRowsInSection.

here is the code:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *) pickerView    numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

     NSUInteger count = 0;

     if (self.schoolPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.school count];
     }
     if (self.majorPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.major count];
     } 
     if (self.classPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.classPicker count];
     }
     if (self.nationalityPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.nationality count];
     }
     if (self.commuterPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.commuter count];
     }
     if (self.honorsPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.honors count];
     }
     if (self.varsityAthletePicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.varsityAthlete count];
     }
     return count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *count = 0;

    if (self.schoolPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.school objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (self.majorPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.major objectAtIndex:row];
    }
     if (self.classPicker) {
         count = [self.infoLibrary.classPicker objectAtIndex:row];
    }
     if (self.nationalityPicker) {
        count = [self.infoLibrary.nationality objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (self.commuterPicker) {
        count = [self.infoLibrary.commuter objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (self.honorsPicker) {
        count = [self.infoLibrary.honors objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (self.varsityAthletePicker) {
        count = [self.infoLibrary.varsityAthlete objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about your question, because numberOfRowsInSection: is a method of UITableViewDataSource, not UIPickerViewDataSource. That said, there is a consistent problem with the code you posted. In your methods, you seem to be testing for which picker view it is by, for example, checking:

```
if (self.schoolPicker) { }
```

...which only checks to see if that picker view exists, not whether it is the one for which the method is being called.

You want to instead check with:

```
if (pickerView==self.schoolPicker) { }
```